How to get object´s VideoPlayer Component to play on MainCamera and stop/destroy on Unity 3D
Hello everyone I am really new to Unity programming and logic. I am developing a game were a player hits letter "F" to interact with the object and the expected outcome is for that objects´s videoPlayer component with the attached video to play the video on the main camera and then close. I am finding really dificult to do this..please help me, thank you I will put down below my 2 C# scripts.
C# Interactable(object script):
    public GameObject otherGameObject;
    public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

    Outline outline;
    public string message;
    public UnityEvent onInteractable;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //videoPlayer = otherGameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        //var videoPlayer = GetComponent<Camera>().AddComponent<UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer>();
        //videoPlayer = GameObject.Find("Cube").GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
        outline = GetComponent<Outline>();
        DisableOutline();
    }

    public void Interact()
    {
        videoPlayer.Play();
        onInteractable.Invoke();
    }


    public void DisableOutline()
    {
        outline.enabled = false;
    }
   
    public void EnableOutline()
    {
        outline.enabled = true;
    }
}

PlayerInteraction (Player C# script):
public class PlayerInteraction : MonoBehaviour
{

public float playerReach = 3f;
Interactable currentInteractable;   
// Update is called once per frame
public void Update()
{
   CheckInteraction();
   if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F) && currentInteractable != null) 
   {
    currentInteractable.Interact();   
   }
}

void CheckInteraction()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = new Ray(Camera.main.transform.position, Camera.main.transform.forward);

    //if colliders with anything within player reach
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, playerReach))
    {
        if(hit.collider.tag == "Interactable") //if looking at an interactable object
        {
            Interactable newInteractable = hit.collider.GetComponent<Interactable>();
            
            newInteractable.videoPlayer.Play();

            //if there is a currentInteractable and it is not the newInteractable
            if(currentInteractable && newInteractable != currentInteractable)
            {
                currentInteractable.DisableOutline();
            }

            if(newInteractable.enabled)
            {
                SetNewCurrentInteractable(newInteractable);
            }
            else //if new interactable is not enabled
            {
                DisableCurrentInteractable();
            }
        }    
        else //if not an interactable
        {
            DisableCurrentInteractable();
        }
        
    }
    else //if nothing in reach
    {
        DisableCurrentInteractable();
    }
}

void SetNewCurrentInteractable(Interactable newInteractable)
{
    currentInteractable = newInteractable;
    currentInteractable.EnableOutline();
}

void DisableCurrentInteractable()
{
    if(currentInteractable)
    {
        currentInteractable.DisableOutline();
        currentInteractable = null;
    }
}

}

I already saw multiple videos on youtube and also documentation ... my idea is that in every object to have a videoPlayer component with a specific video, so each time he clicks on diferent object the video will be diferent.
